# Auto increment entity id for datastore in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I know auto increment is not supported in datastore.
But some how is it possible to create unique id and greater than previous one id in java. I know java support `UUID` this is unique but not in any sequence.

Why I need auto increment is that if somehow I manage auto increment I can get result in sequence order. I didn't need to apply any extra filter to sort the datastore results. I read somewhere datastore return `ASC` order by default. If I create unique id in sequence I can get result already in order format.

I'm using objectify.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard problem in distributed systems. How precise does the ordering need to be? If it needs to be exactly monotonic then you need to have a single-node arbiter that issues ids. Otherwise you're entering the realm of distributed consensus algorithms, which are complex and slow.

The datastore is a massively distributed system and not designed for this particular use case. If you can live with issuing a couple ids per second, you could just store the current value in an entity and updated it in a transaction... but you can't exceed that throughput.